# Android studio - WiFi debugging - device offline

Tags: android, android-studio

My development environment is on virtual machine. So I install apps from Android Studio via WiFi.

I connect phone to my desktop computer and run `adb tcpip 5555` command on it.
And than on virtual computer I can run `adb connect {phone IP}` to connect phone. After that phone is visible in Android studio and I can run apps on my phone from it.

That worked for all of my phones till now. 
Now I have Samsung S9 and S10e phones. Connection works and I can see them in Android Studio. But when I choose Run App and app starts installing it looks like the phone drops WiFi connection.

Android studio reports:

```
11/05 10:41:11: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-G970F.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'device offline'
```

After that phone gains back WiFi connection immediatelly. I looks like that install command kills WiFi connection.

Does anybody have any tip how to prevent this?

Comment: use below answer and tell me is it working or not

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Settings --> Additional settings --> Developer options --> Turn Off MIUI optimization
```

Or

```
Settings --> Developer options --> Turn Off MIUI optimization
```

Comment: I don't have this setting on S10e (also used setting search and it didn't find nothing similar). Will check S9 tommorow morning.

Comment: Both of the phones have One UI. So there is no MIUI related settings.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your mobile settings

Comment: Which settings? Developer options? There would be 12 screenshots for them alone.

Comment: So Just post them

Comment: One more feature I didn't know about: scroll capture. Here are all Developer options in one screenshot: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yFuKveWdBCD6Gz6sJjvquFWmkLSJT6Qa/view?usp=sharing)